# How can I control a window's 'state' (maximize, minimize, restore) with a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to run this script and have it maximize a window if it isn't already maximized.  And restore the window if it isn't.  The window is just whatever is currently active so no need to get specific (but bonus points if you do) 8O)

I plan on activating it from a short-cut keystroke.

It does need to run under PS v1 (I know, I know, but I don't have control over the version at work).

Thanks.

Clarification: Since I cannot update PS to v2, I can't install separate applications either.  Is there a way to do this with native commands?

Answer (score 2):

Set-WindowPosition – set any one of (or all of) top, left, width, height on a window … or maximize/minimize/restore

Get-WindowPosition – get the position (kind-of redundant, actually, since the Window object has it’s position as a property)

http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$a = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$a.BackgroundColor = "white"
$a.ForegroundColor = "black"

$size = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize
$size.Width = 80
$size.Height = 30
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize = $size
```

But this doesn't:

```
$position = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.Windowposition
$position.X = 0
$position.Y = 30
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.Windowposition = $position
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just in case you are doing this on your own or your workplace allows open source modules:**

I used the UIAutomation powershell module (http://uiautomation.codeplex.com/).
Here is my powershell script to move a window to another monitor(which required going to normal and maximize modes).

```
Start-Process Chrome    
##orient new chrome window in full screen on left monitor
#get reference to new chrome window
$nextWin = Get-UiaWindow -Name "*New Tab*"
#transform window to "restore" mode (make sure window is not maximized)
$nextWin.SetWindowVisualState("Normal")
#move window to left monitor
$nextWin.Move(-1920,0)
#maximize window
$nextWin.SetWindowVisualState("Maximize")
```

Of course the main takaways here are:

```
$nextWin.SetWindowVisualState("Normal")
$nextWin.SetWindowVisualState("Maximize")
$nextWin.SetWindowVisualState("Minimize")
```

And there are quite a few options for getting a window ($nextWin) including a **Get-UiaActiveWindow**