# Open Visual Studio Minimized in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking to make a batch file to open all relevant programs on my comp when need to, but I want Visual Studio to open minimized. I know that some programs won't open minimized even with the "/min" param, but is there any way to force it to with other params or to minimize an open window?

If it's not possible, can someone provide an explanation about WHY some programs cant?

Comment: You could try doing it from a powershell script: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/10/powertip-start-a-process-in-a-minimized-window-by-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: @jessehouwing probably the best way to do this. If you submit an answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: I would take a look at this post! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813455/how-can-i-control-a-windows-state-maximize-minimize-restore-with-a-powers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how to do it in a Batch Script. That `/min` switch is something each application itself should have to implement and support and I know no applications that actually do this. You can, however, use PowerShell to accomplish what you're after.

[This blog post explains the simple step to](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/10/powertip-start-a-process-in-a-minimized-window-by-using-powershell.aspx) take:

```
 Start-Process notepad.exe -WindowStyle Minimized
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "start" with the "MIN" switch to start any application minimized.